# How to keep Cocoa Touch framework up to date in applications

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a small (cocoa touch) framework, lets call it *"MyBaseFunctions"* (Just a storyboard with a simple view and a viewcontroller that has functions to alter the view). The framework maintained storyboard and viewcontroller are to be the view of every application that is going to use the framework.

What i'm trying to figure out is how to keep applications that use *"MyBaseFunctions"* up to date with the latest version (or build) of *"MyBaseFunctions"*. (So basically what cocoapods does with versioning where you check if there are new versions with the "pod install" command).

So to sum up what's blurry to me:

- Can I add a framework to a cocoapod and use "pod install" whenever I got    a new version of *"MyBaseFunctions"* for every application that uses the framework?
- Or should I just import the framework again everytime I altered it to every application that uses it?

In case i'm totally off course with my approach for this situation, please tell me so (and how I should do it).

A big thanks upfront for any help or tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your framework is open-source, I don't see any problem in distributing through pods. Cocoapods will do all the work with its own hands. On the other side, if you have no intention to show framework code, you can distribute it in binary form.

Another question is a frequency of changes you are making to the framework. If they are a rare case you may prefer just importing building and importing, in other cases, it may be far better to manage dependencies with a particular tool.

BTW, many companies are (or were) distributing their libraries and APIs with pods, FB and Twitter among others. And it is totally OK.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response, but nonetheless: thank you very much. Your reponse was certainly of value to me in this particular case!

Answer (score 0):

Simply you add the version of framework that you are currently using in pod file. like that:- pod 'SDWebImage', '3.7.3'
because of this u don't get any problems in your code after framework update there pods. I hope it will work for you!!